# R functions glue vs paste

Tags: r, string

I recently discovered the glue package.
After a little bit of research I couldn't figure out why `glue::glue` should be preferred over `paste`:

- According to [this site](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glue/vignettes/speed.html), glue is slower than `paste`.
- The syntax of glue is similar and in no way easier to read than the syntax of paste.

However, in the link from above, the authors say that `paste` does not do string interpolation (only string insertion). I don't really know what this means.

Can some clarify why the `glue` package is interesting and what is meant by string insertion?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**:
After the first feedback I want to ask a more precise question.

Are there any situations where one of `paste` or `glue` would clearly be preferred over the other?

I am trying to understand why someone put in the effort to create the glue package.

Comment: About your question about why use glue, as I said in my answer it's out of scope here so I prefer to answer as a comment, for me it's more readable, and you have more advanced features, like `glue_data`, which doesn't have a direct base equivalent.

Comment: Your new question is still too broad, this question could be more suited to https://community.rstudio.com/ . You could also look at the help page of glue and at the vignettes. with glue you can set the evaluation environment as a parameter; where you'd need `eval` with `paste`, you also have the `transformer feature` which can be really neat.

Answer (score 5):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation) says :

> In computer programming, string interpolation (or variable interpolation, variable substitution, or variable expansion) is the
>   process of evaluating a string literal containing one or more
>   placeholders, yielding a result in which the placeholders are replaced
>   with their corresponding values.

`paste` doesn't look into the strings that are passed to it to replace some characters by others, that's why it doesn't do interpolation.

According to this definition I'm not sure why one would say `sprintf` doesn't do interpolation (as it's mentioned on your link), it might be because the placeholders are not explicit as they are in glue, but I think this assertion is debatable.

Your question about why glue is good is unfortunately out of scope here as it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
Of course using one over the other can be a matter of opinion. 
I added a question, maybe you can have a look.