# How to use max of a variable in title/subtitle of a plot with glue in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a user defined function that calculates daily covid cases for a given country and gives out a data frame:

```
fn_daily_cases <- function(Country_Name = India)
  {
  Country_Name <- rlang::quo_name(rlang::enquo(Country_Name))
  # above line will insert quote to the value in variable Country_Name
  
  df_gather %>% filter(Country.Region == Country_Name) %>% 
    mutate(daily_cases = abs(Cases_Count - lag(Cases_Count, default = 0))) %>% 
    # at beginning it will give 0 instead of NA
    
    arrange(desc(Date))
  
  } 

fn_daily_cases(Spain)

####### output ########

Country.Region Date   Cases_Count daily_cases
<chr>          <date> <int>       <dbl>

Spain   2020-12-11  1730575 10519   
Spain   2020-12-10  1720056 7955    
Spain   2020-12-09  1712101 9773    
Spain   2020-12-08  1702328 0   
Spain   2020-12-07  1702328 17681   
Spain   2020-12-06  1684647 0   
Spain   2020-12-05  1684647 0   
Spain   2020-12-04  1684647 8745    
Spain   2020-12-03  1675902 10127   
Spain   2020-12-02  1665775 9331
```

**Issue:** When I try to plot this dataframe using another function then I am unable to display `max( Cases_Count)` in **subtitle**

```
library(glue)
library(tidyverse)

fn_daily_cases_plot <- function(country_selected = India) {
  
  fn_daily_cases({{country_selected}}) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Date, y = daily_cases)) +
  geom_line(col = "midnightblue") +
  labs(title = glue("{quo_name(enquo(country_selected))} Daily Cases") ,
       subtitle = glue("Total cases so far: {max(Cases_Count)}" )
       ) +
  theme_light()
}
```

```
fn_daily_cases_plot(Spain)


##### output ######

Error in eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir) : object 'Cases_Count' not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to first save the data in a separate `tibble` `x` and then to call
`max(x$Cases_Count)`.

```
fn_daily_cases_plot <- function(country_selected = India) {

  x <- fn_daily_cases({{country_selected}})

  ggplot(x, aes(Date, y = daily_cases)) + 
  geom_line(col = "midnightblue") +
  labs(title = glue("{quo_name(enquo(country_selected))} Daily Cases") , 
        subtitle = glue("Total cases so far: {max(x$Cases_Count)}" )) +
  theme_light() 
}
```

Anyways, I don't know why you prefer `glue` over the base alternative `paste`
(see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53049986/r-functions-glue-vs-paste)).

Comment: thanks @Cettt, I don't understand why it works by assigning it to x & then `max(x$Cases_Count)` but it doesn't work with `max(.$Cases_Count)`. Alot of time I don't understand how R `tidyverse` piping works. In many cases `.$variable` works but it doesn't sometimes so it remains a hit & trial method for me. I am new in R and some people have shown example with glue() in some other questions earlier so I started using glue() instead of sprintf.

Comment: the `magrittr` pipe  `%>%` interprets the rhs as a function and evaluates at in the lhs.
In your version of the code, you only use one pipe: on the lhs you have a dataframe on the rhs you have ggplot function call.
So R draws a plot based on the information in the dataframe. If you want to place the lhs elsewhere in the rhs call, I recommend to read the help site (see ?`%>%`).